# Run a PowerShell script with a specific users within the cmd and display the output in the same console

Tags: powershell, cmd

I used to run PowerShell scripts from cmd by writing the following:"powershell.exe ./script.ps1" and it displays the output within the opened cmd console.

Now, I'm trying to run a PowerShell script with a specific user using the "run as" but the script is run in an external powershell console and the output is not displayed at all. However, if I want to display the output I can add `-noexit` parameter to the powershell but still it displays the output in an external PowerShell console not the Cmd console I'm running the script from. Below is the commands I'm running to trigger the script

```
SET var=%cd%
runas /savecred /user:testuser "powershell.exe %var%/Script.ps1"
```

Is there a workaround to get the output in the same cmd console I'm running this script from?